# site only shows half screen on mobile? Rest of screen is just body background?

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

Ok I have a big problem that I don't know how to get around, I have never encountered this before - half my site won't display on mobile. It is cut in half. I have to present this site in a week and haven't tested on mobile until now - I do not know what to do. Here it is:

[image]

I have a full size image as that top image, and the text from that is extending over, however I don't know what the problem is. I use a few media selector sin my CSS, but only to change various small things.

I read up on setting `site-content` width in CSS - could this be the problem?

Im desperate - how can I fix this?

Comment: Reference to the actual site?

Comment: http://www.inversemedia.com/socialab/cleanup7%20copy/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally, you would have planned for mobile-friendliness. However, a very quick fix to get it not looking terrible is to replace:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

in the HTML with:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5">
```

This will set the screen width to the device width, but not scale the text fully to mobile-friendly sizes, meaning your font will be smaller than it should be, but it will fit. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What would I do in the future as I still have a problem with iPhone 5

Comment: Remove all the `margin-right: -70px;` from the divs in the `peopleBox` div for screen sizes smaller than 370px width by using a media query.